# connman connections extremely flaky and slow

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, dns, network-interface

I'm trying to configure my system to be able to connect via either ethernet or wifi with `connman`. I was able to hotplug my ethernet with `systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` previously, but I'd like to get automatic wifi working.

After installing and enabling the `connman.service`, I can now connect over wifi and ethernet -- but both are **extremely** slow, and drop almost all connections. I've tried disabling `dhcpcd.service` but my problems persist.  I checked, and I do have the correct wifi driver `ath9k`, and I'd assume my ethernet driver is correct because it worked perfectly before.  DNS requests work just fine, which makes me think that something is interfering with my connection ... but what?  I'm not running any other network services, to the best of my knowledge.

`iwconfig` tells me that all of the dropped connections are "invalid misc".

The output of `systemctl status -l connman.service` is:

```
 - connman.service - Connection service
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/connman.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sat 2015-01-31 13:34:40 PST; 2min 46s ago
Main PID: 213 (command)
  CGroup: /system.slice/connman.service
            213 /usr/bin/connmand -n
```

Comment: Look through your journal to see why connman is flaking out. Also, make absolutely sure it is the only network service running.

Comment: @jasonwryan There's nothing in my systemd journal `journalctl` to indicate any errors.

Comment: Then please paste the output of `systemctl status -l connman.service` into your question.

Comment: @jasonwryan Added. Don't see anything there either, but maybe I'm just being dumb.

Comment: You need to let it run until it drops out, to see what is reported, then paste the output.

Comment: @jasonwryan Maybe I should have been clearer. That's all I get, both before and after my internet starts dropping. ( I only mentioned the reboot because I'm using ethernet via `dhcpcd.service` to post onto this page. )

Comment: Then something is wronmg with your setup: it should look like http://sprunge.us/cBdO I suspect you have conflicting services running.